# Convert System.Drawing.Color to RGB and Hex Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, rgb, system.drawing.color

Using C# I was trying to develop the following two. The way I am doing it may have some problem and need your kind advice. In addition, I dont know whether there is any existing method to do the same.

```
private static String HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    String rtn = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        rtn = "#" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //doing nothing
    }

    return rtn;
}

private static String RGBConverter(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    String rtn = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        rtn = "RGB(" + c.R.ToString() + "," + c.G.ToString() + "," + c.B.ToString() + ")";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //doing nothing
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Rod https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750062/what-is-meaning-of-tostringx2

Answer (score 257, accepted):

I'm failing to see the problem here.  The code looks good to me.

The only thing I can think of is that the try/catch blocks are redundant -- Color is a struct and `R`, `G`, and `B` are bytes, so `c` can't be `null` and `c.R.ToString()`, `c.G.ToString()`, and `c.B.ToString()` can't actually fail (the only way I can see them failing is with a `NullReferenceException`, and none of them can actually be `null`).

You could clean the whole thing up using the following:

```cs
private static String ToHex(System.Drawing.Color c)
    => $"#{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}"
    
private static String ToRGB(System.Drawing.Color c)
    => $"RGB({c.R},{c.G},{c.B})"
```

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that empty try-catch blocks should (almost) universally be eradicated.  They have great potential to lead to buggy code, if not now then down the road when this code is modified.  Still, +1 for the cleaned up code, and to the OP +1 for a well-framed question.

Comment: Took me a while to find the VB equivelant: String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", c.R, c.G, c.B)

Comment: I post an adaptation of your code to C#6 as an alternative answer. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37821008/1248177).

Comment: This will produce the wrong color if the color has an alpha channel (transparency).  You will get full opaqueness.

Comment: @LarryBud Absolutely true, and thank you for pointing it out.  My example skipped the alpha channel only because I was keying off of the original question, which also didn't include it. :)

Comment: @LarryBud [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37821008/1248177) supports alpha channel

Answer (score 218):

You could keep it simple and use the native color translator:

```
Color red = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000");
string redHex = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(red);
```

Then break the three color pairs into integer form:

```
int value = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: But if I do this way,
        Color red = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

        string redHex = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(red);

it does not provide the Hex Value.

Comment: Certainly should do, I tested that code specifically and got #"FF0000". What are you getting? You might also like to refer to the MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml.aspx

Comment: Try with Color red = System.Drawing.Color.Red; --> it does not provide #FF0000.

Comment: So using exactly the first code block I provided, what is the value of redHex? I think something on your side is missing.

Comment: The code you have provided works but when I change the first line of your code to : Color red = System.Drawing.Color.Red;  --> Then it does not give the hex code. It gives "Red" as an output.

Comment: @Hoque - Confirmed. ColorTranslator gives a "friendly" name to the color.  How annoying!

Comment: +1 bc this caused me to look at the .NET implementation of `ColorTranslator` which is the accepted answer + `KnownColor` logic. i didn't want that logic, so i went with the accepted answer (but made extension methods)

Comment: This may not be suitable for some cases, because a quick test within a WinForm lead to the following result: `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Me.BackColor) = "buttonface"` instead of the (desired) hex value.

Comment: One other thing to be aware is that any `Alpha` values of your color are lost!

Answer (score 57):

If you can use C#6 or higher, you can benefit from [Interpolated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) and rewrite [@Ari Roth's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395708/1248177) like this:

C# 6:

```
public static class ColorConverterExtensions
{
    public static string ToHexString(this Color c) => $"#{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}";

    public static string ToRgbString(this Color c) => $"RGB({c.R}, {c.G}, {c.B})";
}
```

Also:

- I add the keyword `this` to use them as extensions methods.
- We can use the type keyword `string` instead of the class name.
- We can use lambda syntax.
- I rename them to be more explicit for my taste.

Edit: If you want to support the alpha channel:

```
public static class ColorConverterExtensions
{
    // #RRGGBB
    public static string ToHexString(this Color c) => $"#{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}";

    // RGB(R, G, B)
    public static string ToRgbString(this Color c) => $"RGB({c.R}, {c.G}, {c.B})";

    // #RRGGBBAA
    public static string ToHexaString(this Color c) => $"#{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}{c.A:X2}";

    private static double ToProportion(byte b) => b / (double)Byte.MaxValue;

    // RGBA(R, G, B, A)
    public static string ToRgbaString(this Color c) => $"RGBA({c.R}, {c.G}, {c.B}, {ToProportion(c.A):N2})";
}
```

Fun fact: I have to search about the *proportion* name, because we want for a value in the interval `[0, 1]` not a percent which is in the interval `[0, 100]`

- https://english.stackexchange.com/a/286524/70403
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218655/a-number-between-0-and-1-like-a-percentage-but-expressed-as-a-decimal
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890617/name-for-percentage-as-a-decimal-between-0-and-1-inclusive
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626783/is-there-a-name-for-numbers-between-0-and-1

Answer (score 34):

e.g.

```
 ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(Color.Tomato.ToArgb()))
```

This can avoid the KnownColor trick.

Answer (score 3):

I found an extension method that works quite well

```
public static string ToHex(this Color color)
{
    return String.Format("#{0}{1}{2}{3}"
        , color.A.ToString("X").Length == 1 ? String.Format("0{0}", color.A.ToString("X")) : color.A.ToString("X")
        , color.R.ToString("X").Length == 1 ? String.Format("0{0}", color.R.ToString("X")) : color.R.ToString("X")
        , color.G.ToString("X").Length == 1 ? String.Format("0{0}", color.G.ToString("X")) : color.G.ToString("X")
        , color.B.ToString("X").Length == 1 ? String.Format("0{0}", color.B.ToString("X")) : color.B.ToString("X"));
}
```

Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c77ba6c-6659-4a46-920a-7261dd4a15d0/how-to-convert-rgba-value-into-its-equivalent-hex-code?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: I belive it should be Hex2, not Hex, otherwise the color maybe wrong interpolated.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Where would Hex2 go in the code, I have seen colours being slightly different sometimes?

Comment: I meant `X2` instead of `X`, otherwise you might get `1` instead of `01` then it will be a problem.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Yeah, with `X2` then you don't need all the `color.B.ToString("X").Length == 1 ? ` ternaries.

Comment: To make this work with web browsers I had to switch the formatting so that the alpha parameter would be added last.

Answer (score 3):

For hexadecimal code try this

1. *Get* ARGB (Alpha, Red, Green, Blue) representation for the color
2. *Filter out* Alpha channel: `& 0x00FFFFFF`
3. Format out the value (as hexadecimal "X6" for hex)

For RGB one

1. Just *format out* `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` values

Implementation

```
private static string HexConverter(Color c) {
  return String.Format("#{0:X6}", c.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF);
}

public static string RgbConverter(Color c) {
  return String.Format("RGB({0},{1},{2})", c.R, c.G, c.B);
}
```