# Generate a color object from string color

Tags: c#

I want to convert RGB string to hex-color code. For example :

```
   string rgb = rgb(0, 0, 255);
```

From above RGB I want to get:

```
   string hex = #0000FF;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2395708/97966

Comment: your title and question do not match. Which way do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in [ColorTranslator.ToHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.tohtml%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
string hex = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(myColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

```
string hex = "#" + rgb.R.ToString("X2") + rgb.G.ToString("X2") + rgb.B.ToString("X2");
```