# Convert Brush to String to Save in EF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, tostring, brush

Im creating an application that has incorporated a calendar event for users to effectively use. As part of the features, I want the user to be able to save a colour to the event that they add. i.e; set the background of the event to red.

So far, I am using a `colourpicker` from the WPFToolKit, to which i bind to the `brush` property, like so;

```
<xceed:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding CurrentEvent.Color, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"
AvailableColorsHeader="Knowned appointments"DisplayColorAndName="True" ShowAvailableColors="True" ShowStandardColors="True" ShowAdvancedButton="False" UsingAlphaChannel="False"/>
```

However, because I am using a database, I am not to sure what the best approach is to save the brush. I have looked into using [this universal converter](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/07/09/a-universal-value-converter-for-wpf.html) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried to following to save the brush to the database like so;

```
using (var context = new DBEntities())
        {
            //...
            app.Colour = a.Color.ToString();

            context.AddToAppointments(app);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But it throws the following message; `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Therefore, what would be the best option for me to go around? Would it best for me to convert the Brush to a string before saving it? and if so, how could this be done?

Comment: Color.ToString() would propably only return the type definition of you object, dont think that the tostring is overridden. You should save the HEX or RGB code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395438/convert-system-drawing-color-to-rgb-and-hex-value

Answer (score 0):

Your `Color` is null. You want to check for null there.