# How to get System.Windows.Media.Color From From HEX Windows 8 Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to set Border background color from web color value in my **windows 8 mobile application .**

I found one method that convert hex to Argb but its not working for me ..

```
  private System.Windows.Media.Color FromHex(string hex)
        {
            string colorcode = hex;
            int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & -16777216) >> 0x18),
                                  (byte)((argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10),
                                  (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 8),
                                  (byte)(argb & 0xff));


        }
```

I am using above method like..

```
     Border borderCell = new Border();
     var col = FromHex("#DD4AA3");
     var color =new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(col);
     borderCell.Background = color;
```

But if I pass color hex value like below

```
            var col = FromHex("#FFEEDDCC");
```

its works fine but it not work on my hex color value.

Before posting this question I go thru this stack answer.
[How to get Color from Hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

[Convert System.Drawing.Color to RGB and Hex Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395438/convert-system-drawing-color-to-rgb-and-hex-value)

Comment: I cannot understand your this line `its works fine but it not work on my hex color value.` what does it mean "It not work on my hex color value."? the second thing is that you are supplying alpha value in second example `#FFEEDDCC`. make sure that your method converts hex value if it has been supplied with alpha value (first two characters)

Comment: The System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter class is normally helpful to make the conversion.  But it is not available on a phone so you basically need to duplicate [this code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Parsers.cs,53f793cda4dc02b2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

finally I found one method that return color from hex string

```
 public System.Windows.Media.Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
    {
        //remove the # at the front
        hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

        byte a = 255;
        byte r = 255;
        byte g = 255;
        byte b = 255;

        int start = 0;

        //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
        if (hex.Length == 8)
        {
            a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            start = 2;
        }

        //convert RGB characters to bytes
        r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        return System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

Comment: Your effort totally worth it !!

Answer (score 22):

Why not simply use `System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter`?

```
Color color = (Color)System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#EA1515");
```

Comment: Because this question about `Windows-phone` not related to `WPF`.

Comment: Bah humbug.  I misread the article too and found exactly what i was looking for here. :)

Comment: Perfect! Searching for this for sometime !!