# Modify a Custom Property with a Custom Color

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

Happy Holiday

I wish to add a Custom Color with Transparency to a Custom Property in MS Chart Control on the Candle Stick Chart.  I'm getting stuck with the color in quotes.  Nothing has worked for me, anyone run into this?

Here's what I have, I'd like to create a color that has a transparency, but since its between quotes nothing for me has worked besides system colors like "Red", "Green"...
any help appreciated,
Thanks in advance

```
chtCandleStick.Series[0].Points[ttPoint]["PriceDownColor"] = "Maroon";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after trial and error.  Need to convert the ARGB to Hex, works great

```
defaultGreen = "#" + 50.ToString("X2") + 0.ToString("X2") + 200.ToString("X2") + 0.ToString("X2");
```

chtCandleStick.Series[0].Points[ttPoint]["PriceUpColor"] = defaultGreen;

Thanks to: [Convert System.Drawing.Color to RGB and Hex Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395438/convert-system-drawing-color-to-rgb-and-hex-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points[ttPoint]["PriceUpColor"] = "Green"; 
Chart1.Series[0].Points[ttPoint]["PriceDownColor"] = "White"; 
Chart1.Series[0].Points[ttPoint].Color = Color.DarkSlateGray; 
Chart1.Series[0].Points[ttPoint].BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Hope that this could help you. I was referring to [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da29f2e0-9920-41ea-8ac1-58a3c2b103e1/changing-the-color-of-wicks-in-candlestick-charts?forum=MSWinWebChart)

Comment: Thanks, but, the Border Color is the color the Border's the Candle Stick.  I'm looking to change the color inside the border.