# Read and preset a combobox of color properties

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

From a tutorial I have the following combobox:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox_warnColor" Margin="5,0,5,0" SelectionChanged="comboBox_warnColor_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                                <TextBlock Name="PART_ColorName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I populate it like this:

```
comboBox_warnColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
```

I want to save the selected item in a text file to load it to the combobox later again.

**What value could I save to use it for that scenario?**
or
**What would be a good ID value for default defined colors?**

SelectedIndex aside I couldn't find one.

Comment: Have you looked in to SelectedItem? It returns the same Type as in your ItemSource Collection. You could extract the Name or whatever properties you want from that.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Of course I could do something like `comboBox_warnColor.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(' ')[1]` to extract it, but that doesn't seem like good style.

Comment: So your actual question is, what would be a good ID value for default defined colors?

Comment: Exactly. I added your wording as my question.

Comment: Did you already try `<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedName}" ...` with `SelectedName` being a property in your `DataContext`?

Comment: I have just tried it. Works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue` like follows:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedName}" Name="comboBox_warnColor" Margin="5,0,5,0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="12" Height="12" Margin="0,2,5,2" />
                <TextBlock Name="PART_ColorName" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

In Code behind:

```
public class VeryUnrefinedViewmodel
{
    public string SelectedName { get; set; }
}

// ...

VeryUnrefinedViewmodel _DataContextInstance = new VeryUnrefinedViewmodel();
// your initialization code
comboBox_warnColor.ItemsSource = typeof(Colors).GetProperties();
comboBox_warnColor.DataContext = _DataContextInstance;
// _DataContextInstance.SelectedName will contain the name of the selected color
```

You can programmatically pre-select a color by setting an initial value for `SelectedName`. If you want to change the selection dynamically, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the viewmodel.

```
 VeryUnrefinedViewmodel _DataContextInstance = new VeryUnrefinedViewmodel() { SelectedName = "Yellow" };
```

Comment: It works, but I think it's a bit inconvenient. On the other hand that may also apply to my program as well.

Comment: @MarcoFrost I guess it is inconvenient because your application is not in MVVM design, so you have different boilerplate code. By the way (I didn't even think of that before): you could just access the `comboBox_warnColor.SelectedValue` in code behind instead of working with datacontext and viewmodel... Maybe thats more in line with the rest of your code.

Comment: Well, that is just too easy. I didn't know the combo box would accept a string as a value to select an item. There are two child controls in that combo box after all.

Comment: @MarcoFrost its the awesomeness of `SelectedValuePath` - working like a charm as long as each item has some sort of unique value property.

Comment: Ah, I see. So without `SelectedValuePath` there wouldn't be the easy way of `comboBox_warnColor.SelectedValue = "Aqua"`?

Comment: @MarcoFrost you can think of `SelectedValue` as `SelectedItem.<SelectedValuePath>` for the getter and `SelectedItem = ItemsSource.FirstOrDefault(x => x.<SelectedValuePath> == value)` for the setter. Of course, it's a bit more complicated in the end.

Answer (score 0):

[RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) can in unique mode determine a color, so maybe you would want to store that as ID.
And you can convert your color to/from RGBA using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2395438/5246145).

Comment: I already thought of that. Problem is, with the mentioned way of populating the ComboBox, I cannot directly select the item via rgba value.

Comment: You can have a converter in your binding to translate RGBA to Color.