# How to format a System.Windows.Media.Color in XAML using StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, converters, string-formatting

I need to present `System.Windows.Media.Color` in a `TextBlock` formatted as hexadecimal `#rrggbb`. Binding a color like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}"/>
```

results in a string formatted like `#aarrggbb`. I know I could create my own converter to get the desired format, but I don't like the effort. I wondered if there is no other, much simpler way.

I know, defining formats of a `DateTime` could be easily done like

```
StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}
```

Similar to this solution I tried

```
StringFormat={}{0:#rrggbb}
```

but the result is

> sc#1rrggbb, rrggbb, 1rrggbb, 1rrggbb

Is there a way to use `StringFormat` to format the color? If yes, whats the corret syntax?

Comment: you need hex code right ?

Comment: Yes @sifavahora , I forgot to mention this at the question.

Comment: try this  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395477/5742206

Comment: I am looking for a pure XAML solution @sifavahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after searching a lot, I think it's not possible to format a `Color` as simple as a `DateTime`. My solution requires a few lines more but basically it's the same. Using `MultiBinding` it's possible to put the formatted color values together like:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}">
            <Binding Path="Color.R"/>
            <Binding Path="Color.G"/>
            <Binding Path="Color.B"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure xaml solution. Note that `Run` tags should be in one line or you get whitespaces between rgb values.

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Color}" Text="#">
    <Run Text="{Binding R, StringFormat={}{0:X}}"/><Run Text="{Binding G, StringFormat={}{0:X}}"/><Run Text="{Binding B, StringFormat={}{0:X}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```