# Get System.Drawing.Color value as ARGB Hex code

Tags: c#, colors

I want to get `System.Drawing.Color` value in ARGB Hex format, e.g. `Color.Red` as `ffff0000` in an easy way.

In general, it can be obtained from the `Name` property of the `System.Drawing.Color` struct:

```
using System.Drawing;

var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff0000");
Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
```

output: `ffff0000`

But there is a problem if the value is provided as *known color*:

```
using System.Drawing;

var color = Color.Red;
Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
```

output: `Red`

I applied the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2395438/2869093) to convert `System.Drawing.Color` value to RGB code and I prefixed the code with `ff` for alpha channel:

```
var c = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
Console.WriteLine("ff" + c.R.ToString("X2") + c.G.ToString("X2") + c.B.ToString("X2"));
```

output: `ffff0000`

but I found another solution that can be used to get ARGB value as Hex code (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARGB Hex code may be obtained from the `Name` property for *known colors* by converting it to ARGB and back to `System.Drawing.Color` struct:

```
using System.Drawing;

var color = Color.Red;
color = Color.FromArgb(color.ToArgb());
Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
```

output: `ffff0000`

Comment: just noticed you wanted an the Alpha in the HEX so i removed my answer. 99% of the time when i see hex is required it's because transparency is not supported.

Comment: I have the case now where transparency is not supported but it is required... Thanks for help.